# Сессионная кука PHP до и после строки session_start()

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Имею две сессии - синий блок и красный. 
В первой - синий блок - сохраняю в базе параметры одним инсертом после строки session_start() в коде php.
43 - первая загрузка.
44, 45, 46 - обновил по F5.

---

Во второй - красный блок - сохраняю в базе параметры двумя инсертами до и после строки session_start().
47 и 48 - первая загрузка.
49, 50 и 51, 52 - обновил по F5.

---

Данные снимаю так :
число элементов массива куки - count($_COOKIE);
все ключи массива куки (в строку через запятую) - implode(", ", array_keys($_COOKIE));
значение куки по ключу 'PHPSESSID' - $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];

---

Если правильно понял, то в строке 48 :
три элемента массива куки, три ключа массива, а по ключу PHPSESSID просто пустая строка, - колонка cookies_phpsessid.
А в строке 43 :
два элемента массива куки, два ключа, ну а в колонке cookies_phpsessid, - соответственно ничего, поэтому тоже [null].
Почему строки 43 и 48 разные ? 
Как снятие данных в 47 строке приводит к появлению ключа PHPSESSID с пустым значением ? Спасибо.